Apache piped log program failling
I am trying to send apache logs to graylog server but always have the same probleme
AH00106: piped log program '/home/ubuntu/nc/nc_wrapper.sh -w1 10.0.0.126 12201' failed unexpectedly

apache 2.2 has to be considered as EOL, why not migrate to 2.4? and what is this ominous script? What's inside it?
